# Python: Finding average of a nested list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Now I want to find the average of these inner list so that

```
a = [(1+4+7)/3,(2+5+8)/3,(3+6+9)/3]
```

'a' should not be a nested list in the end. Kindly provide an answer for the generic case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [sum(x)/len(x) for x in itertools.izip(*a)]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 12):

```
a = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*a)]
# a is now [4, 5, 6] for your example
```

In Python 2.x, if you don't want integer division, replace `sum(x)/len(x)` by `1.0*sum(x)/len(x)` above.

[Documentation for zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: +1 for zip, but couldn't you save yourself the trouble of an extra function? ;)

Comment: I figured that the OP didn't know Python too well.  Editing anyway :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you have [numpy](https://numpy.org/) installed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> arr = np.array(a)
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.mean(arr)
5.0
>>> np.mean(arr,axis=0)
array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
>>> np.mean(arr,axis=1)
array([ 2.,  5.,  8.])
```